# Scrutinising Answers - A Problem

Tags: feature-request, comments, questions, answers, voting

I have been part of the Stack Exchange communities since 2011, and I see people commenting on questions, answers, and comments over minor spelling and grammar errors, and about knowledge about a given subject.

I feel that this is pointless, as there is no such thing as a 'perfect answer' - in other words something can always be challenged and just about anybody can do it.

The point of a given community is to add what you think might answer the user's question, and try to help the questioner out.
The editing system may be fine - as long as the poster can choose to accept or decline an edit. But allowing just about anybody to have the ability to down vote and post pedantic comments makes users look bad and defeats the point of this website.

It is also about user rep, not just comments. Just about anybody can choose to down-vote a comment, question, and answer and every vote counts, especially when you're just starting out.

It should be down to diamond moderators to make sure users use spelling and grammar at an acceptable but not too strict threshold. You don't need to know anything really, in order to be a member of a given community.

So I think that commenting on other users' answers is creating a war-zone between people.

It is not needed at all.

Comment: *But allowing anybody to have the ability to down vote and post pedantic comments makes users look bad and defeats the point of this website.* - But not everybody can do this. There are already limits in place: 50 rep to comment on the posts of others, and 125 rep to downvote. This is designed to eliminate trolling, among other things.

Comment: just about anybody then, and its less than 125 and is different per community anyhow. 
it does not matter how much rep you have anyhow, you cant just expect rep to solve everything

Comment: So... I see a lot of complaining here but not an actual request. Are you asking that SE remove the ability of users to downvote, edit, and comment on questions and answers? Because that's like half of the site.

Comment: I suspect that this is a sockpuppet account. It was created only a few months ago.

Comment: The feature request is that comments on answers be removed. This feature request is destined to fail.

Comment: _It is also about user rep not just comments, just about anybody can choose to down-vote a comment, question, and answer and every vote counts, especially when you're just starting out._ You realise comments can't be downvoted, right? And that reputation is unaffected by comment upvotes? Have you not noticed this in your four years in Stack Exchange communities?

Comment: I know comments cannot be downvoted.

Comment: I wonder if this has anything to do with your year long suspension on Super User?

Comment: What on Earth were you thinking doing edits like this http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/462014? and 3 others like it...

Comment: What I find funny is that you have (supposedly) been using SE for 4 years yet you don't know how to use @ mentions or how to edit appropriately.

Answer (score 15):

> I see people commenting on questions, answers, and comments over minor spelling and grammar errors,

I see nothing wrong with correcting people in some cases. For example, the two sentences "Ravenous Bugblatter beasts often make a very good meal *for* visiting tourists" and "Ravenous Bugblatter beasts often make a very good meal *of* visiting tourists" have very different connotations (and results). Comments to change this can be important. Haranguing someone over the confusion of "their" and "they're" (or "there"), however, might not be important in comments - you're right about that.

> I feel that this is pointless, as there is no such thing as a 'perfect answer' - in other words something can always be challenged and just about anybody can do it.

Sure, there's no such thing as perfection, but why not try to be as good as possible? Because you can never reach perfection, there's always room for improvement.

> But allowing just about anybody to have the ability to down vote and post pedantic comments makes users look bad and defeats the point of this website.

1. As I said in the comments, only users with 50 rep or more can comment on all posts, and only users with 125 rep or more can downvote. This actually eliminates a *huge* portion of users (although I don't know just what percentage). It tends to keep the trolls and argumentative folk out, for the most part - which is what is important.
2. Criticism isn't bad. I've been shown to be wrong in answers before - quite a few times. I don't *like* being wrong, but I'd rather be corrected via constructive criticism than leave wrong information out there.

> It is also about user rep not just comments, just about anybody can choose to down-vote a comment, question, and answer and every vote counts, especially when you're just starting out.

Correction: To a new user, comments can be the most important thing. Yeah, rep is a huge motivator in the early stages; anyone who tells you otherwise is lying to your face. But comments are important, perhaps more so. They tell you

- How you can improve formatting.
- How to better address the question.
- How to follow any site guidelines you may have missed.
- How to make your answer/question better.

They can also provide encouragement. Comments aren't supposed to be used for "+1!", but a quick message about what you did right can be very helpful.

> You don't need to know anything really, in order to be a member of a given community.

No. Just no. Not. At. All.

Comment: correcting people can be good as you said but the problem is it can also be abused regardless of rep, and besides, either your answer helps the OP, or it doesn't, there is also the editing system for this. as well as moderation on poor content from actual mods.
-

You shouldn't have to know anything about a given topic to be a part of a community.

Comment: *Any* feature on Stack Exchange can be abused. The thing is, there are systems in place to check this - notably, the flagging system. *You shouldn't have to know anything about a given topic to be a part of a community.* - Again, I dispute this. You should understand the content of posts in order to do anything with them.

Comment: you don't have to understand the content though it will probably have bad consequences if you don't you could still learn something, or use the chat (for example), that does not mean a user cannot choose to sign up.

I have not seen any systems to override pedantic comments.

Comment: @RecycleBin *"I have not seen any systems to override pedantic comments."* Comment flags - That's what they're for.

Comment: no thats for when the rules have been broken

Comment: Too chatty/not constructive flags exist for this reason.

Comment: @RecycleBin They're for a number of things: Rude, Not Constructive, Obsolete, Too Chatty, or Other - for when you need to tell a mod about something not covered in the above. This includes all the things you talked about.

Comment: the mods dont even care unless it is against the rules

Comment: @RecycleBin Speaking on behalf of myself and the dozens upon dozens upon dozens upon dozens of other mods across the network - if I can - I can assure you that we do care about flags on chatty comments.

Comment: comments should be dropped all together unless there from a moderator, The voting system is stupid, it gives no insight into anything

Comment: On Stack Overflow, 14.2% of users can comment, and 8.3% of users can downvote. (Cross-referencing a quick [bucketing query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/389614/500066/user-rep-bins) with the current totals shown on the [leaderboards](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow).)

Comment: @RecycleBin Yes, the voting system **does** give insight into some things - the quality of an answer, whether or not it is correct, whether or not it *actually answers the question*, whether it explains the solution in an easy to understand way. If the voting system had no purpose, it wouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: how does voting say what is bad about a question. when its just a number.

Comment: @RecycleBin Would it make any sense to avoid web sites that have voting systems if you don't like voting systems? Quoting you: "The voting system is stupid". Sounds like you don't like what Stack Exchange is. Maybe there are other sites on the Internet that are closer to what you would like? If the voting system were magically removed from Stack Exchange overnight, it wouldn't be Stack Exchange any more. Don't like voting? Probably don't use Stack Exchange, then.

Answer (score 13):

Actually, these features are pretty much the core of what makes Stack Exchange great.

One problem with the Internet is the ability for anyone to say anything they want without being challenged or affirmed.

Voting (and commenting for suggestions/clarifications) is exactly what distinguishes answers and questions here from the sea of opinions and trash on the greater Internet.

Comment: voting does not make a reply an answer, clicking the answer button does that and only the questioner can do that

Comment: @RecycleBin if I see, on a topic I don't know anything about, answers with 100, 10, and -5 votes, it is completely useful information to me. It absolutely is a "reply" in some sense to an answer.

Comment: you rely on some stupid number rather than reading the comment to see if its credible?

Comment: If you don't know enough about the field to verify the content itself? Yeah. But if it's just some stupid number, I assume you don't vote at all, right?

Comment: if you don't understand the comment then why vote on it its meant to be useful how can it be useful if you don't understand it

Comment: @RecycleBin if I want to read lots of comments to determine if an answer is useful I'll go to Micro$ofts forums. Then I can read all sorts of pointless commentary completely and utterly irrelevant to the question/answer at hand. Trust me, as someone who has used both SE and other help sites, the Stack Exchange model works.

Comment: having pedantic comments on here is just as irrelevant

Comment: @RecycleBin meta sites are intended to be discussions (and not strictly Q/A like the rest of the network).

Comment: well it doesnt look like there discussions to me and how come it says to use the chat for that anyhow, if theres too many comments

Comment: @RecycleBin Have you read the tooltip on the downvote button? It describes exactly why it was downvoted. `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`. People are downvoting your question as they disagree with your feature request because they think it is `not useful`.

Comment: @RecycleBin it is very apparant that your attitude is 'I'm right and anyone disagrees is an idiot'. The fact is that voting is staying, comments are staying, editing is staying whether you like it or not.